# What is the recommended way to inform the server that compressed content is welcome from silverlight client using RestSharp?

Tags: silverlight, restsharp

With the **Accept-Encoding** header being [out of reach](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/575037/provide-support-for-gzip-deflate-compression-when-using-silverlight-client-network-stack), what are my options to accept compressed content anyway?

I am using RestSharp for silverlight (pulled the git repository a minute ago).

Thanks.

Comment: I added GZip support to RestSharp a few weeks ago ([here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/commit/7a7072989abc07868c2fd647bc904c1235197bc9)), but just for Windows Phone; I thought Silverlight worked fine with GZip... doesn't it?

Comment: Being unable to use gzip and RestSharp at the time, I have moved to Hammock since then, which provides gzip support for Silverlight, which does not exist out of the box. Hammock does it with the help of `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Silverlight` assembly.